# Cannot access public member of class in List<Interface>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a list of objects that implement an interface. I can access the interface members, but can't seem to access any additional members declared in the class itself.

```
public interface IItems
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Movie : IItems
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Budget {get;set;}
}

public class Book : IItems
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Pages {get;set;}
}

List<IItems> items = new List<IItems> { new Movie(), new Book() };
```

So now if I try to access `items[0].Budget`, it can't find the `Budget` member. But if I try `items[0].Name`, I can access it.

Comment: All the compiler knows about the items in the list is that they are `IItems`and that the only property the items have is `Name`. They could be books or movies, or any other concrete implementations of that interface. If you want to treat the items as movies, you need to cast them to movie instances, something like : `if (items[0] is Movie m){Console.WriteLine(m.Budget);}`

Comment: Hint for future: the approach I'd have used would be to ask myself "What does the compiler think the type of `items[0]` is?" and possibly check that in the IDE. When you see that the compile-time type is just `IItems`, the rest should click into place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all items in the list are of the type `IItems` and this interface doesn't contain the property `Budget`. If you want to get the budget of the movie, you must first check if the item in the list is a movie and convert its type to `Movie`:

```cs
var movie = items[0] as Movie;
if (movie != null)
{
    // access movie.Budget
}
```

Another way to differentiate between different implementations is to use C# 7 pattern matching in a switch-case:

```cs
switch (items[0])
{
case Movie movie:
    // Do something with movie, like accessing movie.Budget
    break;
case Book book:
    // Do something with book, like accessing book.Pages
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your interface doesn't have Budget as a public member.

If you want to create a list of the abstract type refactor your interface to have `int budget { get; set; }`

This is because your list is evaluating the properties of the abstract type, not the child implementations.